Specify default value for property with multiplicity
Consider I have a Class (or Sysml Block) with a property of type String with a multiplicity of [1..*].
How do I specify in UML or SysML a default value for this property of multiple StringLiterals?
I am using Cameo Systems Modeler.

It might not be currently possible; see: https://issues.omg.org/issues/spec/UML/2.5#issue-48700. However, as a work-around, you might be able to use a String consisting of multiple values separated by a comma or some other token.

ValueSpecifications are defined like this:

A ValueSpecification is the specification of a (possibly empty) set of values.

There are countless ways to specify a set of Values, but for a literal specification UML only includes elements that define one value. For all other ways you can use OpaqueExpressions. This allows for the needed flexibility.
The drawback is, that UML doesn't include an expression language. You have to rely on the languages your tool supports. Cameo does support Groovy, so you can write ["string1","string2"]. The simulation engine will interpret this correctly.
Actually, there is a standard language, albeit in a separate specification: ALF (omg.org/spec/ALF). If you buy the plugin, Cameo can use it. Then it looks like String[]{"string1","string2"}. If available, definitely use this standard.
PS: There was Issue UMLR-790 that asked for changing the multiplicity of the default value. It was dismissed, since ValueSpecifications already allow to define multiple values. Adding a second way would be confusing.

https://issues.omg.org/issues/UMLR-790 has been resurrected as https://issues.omg.org/issues/UAF13-18, apparently. How many of these "Open" issues on the OMG site have actually been dismissed or resolved?

When I said "dismissed" I was referring to internal comments on this issue. It remains officially open, since there hasn't been a voting on it. There are currently no plans to go ahead with voting, so it probably will stay open for the next future.
The UAF13-18 issue on the other hand has been deferred officially, on the ground that UAF is the wrong taskforce. I guess it was by mistake that it had been entered there. Why the official page still shows it as open, even though it has been deferred on the 2nd of september is probably an updating issue.
